# how to get all records of related models and display dynamic data in django

Tags: python, django

I'm new in django.I want to retrieve all the records from related models and display the dynamic data in templates. I tried by using raw sql also but i could not display dynamic data  templates.

models.py:

```
 class NewRegistration(models.Model):
    houseowner_name_en = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ward_no = models.ForeignKey(system_settings.models.Wardno)
    contactno = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    construction_type = models.ForeignKey(system_settings.models.ConstructionType)
    taxpayer_id = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    cen = models.IntegerField()
    is_forwarded = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Application(models.Model):
    registration_date = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    building_use = models.ForeignKey(to=system_settings.models.BuildingUse)
    building_category = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    building_structure_category = models.ForeignKey(to=system_settings.models.BuildingStructureCategory)
    building_storey = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=0)

    reg = models.ForeignKey(NewRegistration)


class Landowner(models.Model):
    landowner_type = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    lo_salutation = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    lo_name_np = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    lo_citizenship_issue_date = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    reg = models.ForeignKey(NewRegistration)
```

views.py:

```
def export(request):
    all_objects = NewRegistrationModel.objects.all()
     # houseowner= all_objects.houseownerinfo_set.all()
    app_all=Application.objects.all()
    landinfo=Landinfo.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'exports.html', {'all_objects': all_objects})
```

Comment: Your explanation of the question is not satisfying. If your goal is getting a fulfilled answer please consider updating the question.

Comment: Hi I am getting,

NameError: name 'system_settings' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it like this.

**views.py**

```
def export(request):
    all_objects = NewRegistration.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'exports.html', {'all_objects': all_objects})
```

**exports.html**

```
# in template when displaying
{% for registration in all_objects %}
    {{ registration.fiscalyear }}
    {% for owner in registration.landowner_set.all %}
        {{owner.landowner_type}}
        {{owner.lo_wardno}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use generic.ListView in your views.py file like that:

```
class Export(generic.ListView):
    model = NewRegistration
    template_name = "your_template_name.html"  

    def get_queryset(self):
        return NewRegistration.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       context = super(Export, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
       context['app_all'] = Application.objects.all()
       context['landinfo'] = Landingo.objects.all()
       return context
```

you can accees the datas in your template like that {{ app_all }} or {{ landinfo }}.

Comment: I got error(AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'export').

Comment: Would you be a little more explanatory?

Comment: Did you add the Export class to your urls file ?

path('all-thing', views.Export.as_view(), name='all-thing')

Comment: I got error.  ImproperlyConfigured at /registration/export/
Export is missing a QuerySet. Define Export.model, Export.queryset, or override Export.get_queryset().

Comment: I don't have Export model. I want to retrieve records from above 3 models

Comment: i edited the answer. Export is not a model. it is a class based view.

Comment: TemplateDoesNotExist at /registration/export/
bps_registration/newregistration_list.html

Comment: then create a template :D

Comment: I created but i got same error. But i want to display the records in export.html

Comment: Create a export.html file and replace template_name ="export.html"

Comment: i m on the phone now. Add your code to github and send me link. i will work on it 4-5 hours later.

Comment: there is nothing in your project

Comment: Sorry, Dogushan KAYA. I was  trying to solve it and i changed the code. So i  didn't push the updated project

Comment: did i help you? :D

Comment: Your welcome. Please confirm my reply and mark as solved :)

Comment: I took idea from your anwer and did  it in a slightly different way.